# Python, logging module not defined with cxfreeze

Tags: python, logging, module, undefined

I want to use CxFreeze for my fist time. I want to implement also logging module which is a standard module in Python 3.6.
I have the last version of CxFreeze install (in 5.1.1)

Here my code !

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os,sys, logging

base = None
executables = [Executable("utt.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna"]
includes = ["logging"]

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
        'includes':includes
    },
}

# On appelle la fonction setup
setup(
    name = "Import ",
    version = "1",
    description = "Gestion rapide",
    options = options,
    executables = executables
)
```

and here the error message

```
C:\Python\Python36\Scripts>C:\Python\Python36\Scripts\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\utt.exe
2018-08-21 17:43:46.354712
2018-08-21-17-43-46
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "utt.py", line 16, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(filename=fileDate,level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s-8s %(message)s')
NameError: name 'logging' is not defined
```

Please, I don't understand why my mdoule isn't defined. i tried Inclues and Packages properties even importing logging libraries with include_files property.

Regards.

Comment: Does your script run when not in the executable? This is a python error, not a cxfreeze error.

Comment: Show us that `utt.py`. Or, better, show us a [mcve], with just enough code to reproduce the problem and nothing else.

Comment: Probably, you forgot to import `logging` in your `utt.py`? Also I think you shouldn't specify `logging` in `included`, because it's a standard module, it's always included implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that wasn't a CXFreeze error. I made a mistake during the setup up my installer. I moved my import  commands to another .py file (which contained config parameter for my code). I misused the import command and thought that nested import was more simple.

I should have test my build without cxfreeze for this modification..

Thank you for your comments, you led me to my mistake.